# Sending Email to Configured User Lists if publishing failed more than 100 pages from Monitoring Services

Tags: 2011, monitoring

I need a monitoring service configured which will keep monitoring my publishing queue and if publishing queue is more than 100 pages, it will send an email to configured user list about the failure.

Any idea how to get the email settings and SMTP details?

Any sample code how to implement this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the nice article explained by Julian. The sample code here uses TOM API, but you could easily replace that with core service API or Powershell.

https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/monitoringtridionpublishingwithtridionapplicationmonitoring.aspx

Core Service API to get the Publish Transactions:

```
PublishTransactionData publishTransaction = _client.GetSystemWideList(new PublishTransactionsFilterData());
```

// loop through the list and check for the status with a counter.

Comment: Hey Ram, Do we need to write another client to trap the Tridion monitoring web service and from there we need to send the email to defined users, I don't think monitoring service will do for us.

Comment: Manoj, If you have already monitoring tool like Nagios or HP BAC or Monit you could setup the tool to use this to send notification. If you don't have any tool then obviously you need to write the notification mechanism.

Comment: Hmm so finally I think we need to trap the SNMP messages, is there any article for how to trap these messages and what configuration done at cd_monitoring.config

Comment: Here the doc link explain how to setup : http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/idheading-359601912 (requires login)